# Get table's column names which are always null

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a table with a lot of columns. Some of them are always `NULL` and does not contain any value.

Is there a way to list those columns using a SQL query instead testing them one by one ?
I'd like to avoid :

```
SELECT Col1 from MyTable where Col1 IS NOT NULL
SELECT Col2 from MyTable where Col2 IS NOT NULL
...
```

Comment: What have you tried? What tables are being utilised?

Comment: What database are you using?

Comment: A Table's structure will never allow you to define an unnamed column.  I assume you either mean you have a query that has hard coded values in it that are unnamed, or you want to find a column whose values are always null.    Could you clarify your question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you are using SQL Server, just assign your table name to `@strTablename`

*In this example I assumed that `dbo.MyTable` is the table name*

```
DECLARE @strTablename  varchar(100) = 'dbo.MyTable'
DECLARE @strQuery  varchar(max) = ''
DECLARE @strUnPivot as varchar(max) = ' UNPIVOT ([Count] for [Column] IN ('

CREATE TABLE ##tblTemp([Column] varchar(50), [Count]  Int)

SELECT @strQuery = ISNULL(@strQuery,'') + 'Count([' + name + ']) as [' + name + ']  ,' from sys.columns where object_id = object_id(@strTablename) and is_nullable = 1
SELECT @strUnPivot = ISNULL(@strUnPivot,'') + '[' + name + '] ,' from sys.columns where object_id = object_id(@strTablename) and is_nullable = 1


SET @strQuery = 'SELECT [Column],[Count] FROM ( SELECT ' + SUBSTRING(@strQuery,1,LEN(@strQuery) - 1) + ' FROM ' + @strTablename + ') AS p ' + SUBSTRING(@strUnPivot,1,LEN(@strUnPivot) - 1) + ')) AS unpvt '

INSERT INTO ##tblTemp EXEC (@strQuery)

SELECT [Column] from ##tblTemp Where [Count] =0

DROP TABLE ##tblTemp
```

Answer (score 2):

`MAX(col)` is null only when all rows are null for this column. So check this for every column and concatenate those names for which the expression is null.

```
  select 
  'null columns: ' +
  case when max(col1) is null then 'col1 ' else '' end +
  case when max(col2) is null then 'col2 ' else '' end +
  case when max(col3) is null then 'col3 ' else '' end +
  case when max(col4) is null then 'col4 ' else '' end +
  ...
from mytable;
```

Comment: I get an errror: Incorrect syntax near '|'.

Comment: Then you are using a DBMS that is not standard compliant. (You forgot to tag your DBMS, so I don't know which it is.) SQL Server for example uses `+` instead of `||` and in MySQL you need the `CONCAT` function for string concatenation.